# Search string in file and print next 5th line in file using autoit

Tags: autoit

I have a text file contains nearly 20 lines wanted to search a string in file and print next 5th line in file using autoit, any one can help me to solve this

```
#include <File.au3>
#include <array.au3>


$file = @ScriptDir & "\file.txt"
$search = "str"

If FileExists($file) Then
    $contents = FileRead($file)
    If @error Then
        MsgBox(0, 'File Error', $file & ' could not be read.')
    Else
        For $i = 1 To $count
            If StringInStr($contents, $search) Then        
                MsgBox(0, 'Positive', $file & ' does contain the text "' & $search & '"')
            Else
                MsgBox(0, 'Negative', $file & ' does NOT contain the text "' & $search & '"')
            EndIf
        Next
    EndIf
EndIf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reads the text file until the search string is found and then writes the next 5 lines to STDOUT:

```
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>


Global $file = @ScriptDir & "\file.txt", $search = "str"
Global $iLine = 0, $sLine = ''
Global $hFile = FileOpen($file)
If $hFile = -1 Then 
    MsgBox(0,'ERROR','Unable to open file for reading.')
    Exit 1
EndIf

; find the line that has the search string
While 1
    $iLine += 1
    $sLine = FileReadLine($hFile)
    If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop

    ; $search found in the line, now write the next 5 lines to STDOUT
    If StringInStr($sLine, $search)And Not $iValid  Then    
        For $i = $iLine+1 To $iLine+5
            ConsoleWrite($i & ':' & FileReadLine($hFile, $i) & @CRLF)
        Next
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
WEnd
FileClose($hFile)
```

**Edit**

Due to Matt's argument here's a 2nd version of the loop that doesn't use the "line" parameter for [FileReadLine](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileReadLine.htm).

```
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>


Global $file = @ScriptDir & "\file.txt", $search = "str"
Global $iLine = 0, $sLine = '', $iValid = 0
Global $hFile = FileOpen($file)
If $hFile = -1 Then 
    MsgBox(0,'ERROR','Unable to open file for reading.')
    Exit 1
EndIf

; find the line that has the search string
While 1
    $iLine += 1
    $sLine = FileReadLine($hFile)
    If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop

    ; test the line for the $search string until the flag $iValid is set
    If StringInStr($sLine, $search) And Not $iValid Then
        $iValid = 1
        ContinueLoop
    EndIf

    If $iValid Then
        $iValid += 1
        ConsoleWrite($iLine & ':' & $sLine & @CRLF)
        If $iValid > 5 Then ExitLoop
    EndIf
WEnd
FileClose($hFile)
```

You won't note much difference between those two versions of the script, unless you are reading a file with 10k+ lines and the lines you are looking for are in the last quarter of that file but it surely is a good idea to prevent possible performance issues.

Comment: Using `FileReadLine` with its second parameter incrementing by one like in the `For...Next` loop above is not a good idea. You won't notice performance in a small script like this but just something to bear in mind.

Comment: @Matt: Yes you got a point there. I will edit my answer and add a different solution.